# how to filter data between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

i want to filter data between two dates. i did coding but getting error. Trying to figure out the problem but couldn't . Please help me.

**HERE IS THE CODE**

```
<?php

 $user='root';
 $pass='';
 $db='mypro_bms';
 $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost',$user,$pass,$db);

 if(isset($_POST['search'])){
 $txtStartDate=$_POST["txtStartDate"];

 $txtEndDate=$_POST["txtEndDate"];
 $q=mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT blood_group, SUM(blood_bag) as sum FROM donate where donation_date BETWEEN '$txtStartDate' and '$txtEndDate' order by donation_date");
 $count=mysqli_num_rows($q);
   }
  ?>
<body>
    <form method="post">
      <input type="date" name="txtStartDate">
      <input type="date" name="txtEndDate">
      <input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
      <?php
          if ($count=="0") 
          {
            echo "No data";          }
            else
            {
              while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($q)) {
               echo"['".$row['blood_group']."',".$row['sum']."],";
              }
            }
```

Comment: What's the error you're receiving?

Comment: Undefined variable: count,  undefined variable q and last one is mysqli_fetch_array() expect parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in

Comment: The undefined variable errors for `$count` and `$q` are because you don't initialize those variables before using them if `$_POST['search'])` isn't set. And because `$q` isn't set, `mysqli_fetch_array()` is complaining.

Comment: The easiest way to fix your issue is to add `$count = 0;` before `if(isset($_POST['search'])){`

Comment: okay thanks i am doing .then inform you

Comment: thanks @jeffwa...its working

Comment: Your code is susceptible to SQL injection. Look at using parameterised queries.

Answer (score 0):

A variable is being accessed outside of its scope.

The body of the `if` statement is ended too early. (This is an example of where *indentation* can help the human reader.)

`$q` and `$count` are declared inside the if block; those variables have local scope within that block, and are out of scope outside the block.

```
 if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    // beginning of block
    $txtStartDate = $_POST['txtStartDate'];
    $txtEndDate   = $_POST['txtEndDate'];
    $q = ... ;
    $count = ... ;
    // references to $q and $count are valid inside the block 
    // block ends at closing curly brace
 }  
 // references to $q and $count are invalid outside the block
```

---

Other notes:

- code pattern appears to be vulnerable to SQL Injection
- variables included in SQL text must be properly escaped (`mysqli_real_escape_string`)

---

To return rows in a given range of dates for `donation_date`

Assuming `donation_date` column is defined as DATE or DATETIME datatype, the normative pattern to find rows in March 2019 would be something like this:

```
 FROM donation d 
WHERE d.donation_date  >= '2019-03-01' 
  AND d.donation_date  <  '2019-04-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to do the same in xamarin form.

here is the Model

```
  using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;

namespace CalculatorPay.Model
{
   public class PayModel
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int PayID { get; set; }
        public DateTime PayDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Stops { get; set; }
        public decimal Ces { get; set; }
        public decimal Miles { get; set; }
        public decimal returns { get; set; }
        public decimal dailyPay { get; set; }
        public decimal TotalPay { get; set; }       
    }
}

here is the xml

    <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CalculatorPay.TotalPage"
             >
    
        <StackLayout>       
            <DatePicker x:Name="dtOne" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"  BackgroundColor="#BBDEFB" Margin="100, 10, 100, 10" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <DatePicker x:Name="dtTwo" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black"  BackgroundColor="#BBDEFB" Margin="100, 10, 100, 10" HorizontalOptions="Center" />       
        <Label x:Name="PayView" Text="$000.00" TextColor="Blue" Margin="10, 0, 0, 0" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Button x:Name="btnShow" Text="SHOW" BackgroundColor="AliceBlue" Margin="110, 10, 110, 10" TextColor="Black" CornerRadius="10" Clicked="btnShow_Clicked"/>            
        </StackLayout>    
</ContentPage>

here is the c# for the xml

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;
using CalculatorPay.Model;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace CalculatorPay
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class TotalPage : ContentPage
    {
      
        public TotalPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }       

    private void btnShow_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           
                using (SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(App.DatabaseLocation))
                {
              
                var seePay =  conn.QueryScalars<PayModel>("SELECT TotalPay FROM PayModel WHERE (PayDate BETWEEN'" + dtOne.Date + "' AND '" + dtTwo.Date + "')");                          
                PayView.Text = String.Format("TOTAL PAY ${0:0.00}", seePay).ToString();
            }        
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).